# How to override user's locale for toStartOfWeek() method, so that system should always return Sunday date as week start date?

Tags: apex, date, locale

```
Date currentDate = System.today();
System.debug('Start of week = '+currentDate.toStartOfWeek());
```

For **English (United States) locale** System.debug will display **Sunday** date as Start of week. And for **English (United Kingdom) locale** System.debug will display **Monday** date as start of week.

Irrespective of user's locale, Always I need to get Sunday date as week start date. Is it possible?

Comment: You can subtract one day from current date, If you get Monday as the startOfWeek.
`Date currentDate = System.today().toStartOfWeek().addDays(-1); `
somthing like this.

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it is below:

Documentation of [date time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) class

```
Datetime currentDatetime = System.now();
date gmtdate = currentDatetime.dateGMT();
System.debug('gmtStart of week = '+gmtdate.toStartOfWeek());
```